# Cloud Formation is not redeploying the APIGateway when we are updating the swagger documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services

APIGATEWAY+SERVERLESS (having AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource ) which is not getting redeploy when I am updating the swagger file.
I believe many people are getting this issue but didnot get the proper resolution if someone is able to resolve it.

Comment: I know nothing about serverless so don't know how much this will apply. However with regular cloudformation, you get ONE deployment, at the time of `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` creation. Subsequent updates to things about the API for example adding new methods or uri resources will not get deployed. We got around this by using a custom resource + macro; the macro always changes a value in the custom resource, which means the custom resource is always executed on any update to the template, and the custom resource in turn redeploys the API.

Comment: can you please share your solution or like help me with how to do it because I am not sure how to do it

Comment: By custom resource you mean custome variable in cloud formation